# What is the meaning of '中国面孔'?

Tags: meaning

I think I know what this '中国面孔' means, but sometimes Chinese surprises me completely.

同时，也说明西门子这样一个跨国公司，已经开始选择完全的中国面孔来拉近和中国的距离。

已经开始选择完全的中国面孔来拉近和中国的距离
(Siemens) has already begun to select only Chinese nationals, in order to narrow the gap with China.

中国面孔 = Chinese faces = Chinese nationals ??

Comment: In my sentence, unless there is some surprising meaning in there, which is why I asked, it should mean 'Chinese citizens'. In another context, it may mean something else. I wouldn't like to speculate on that.

Comment: Give you an example: the other day I had '雄厚的实力‘。 I could not understand it. Turns out, it meant, in my context, 'have a lot of money'

Comment: Reechen, in English we can also say 'There are some new faces around here.' This just means 'new people'. Or 'I want to see more Chinese faces in this company.' That means 'I want to see more Chinese people in this company.' It is a metaphor, whereby 'face' stands for 'person or people or citizens'.

Comment: 有一位尊敬的用户不断向皈依者布道

Answer (score 2):

I've searched some sentences on Baidu, they all mean `Chinese nationals` in the context, i.e. `localization`.

> 西门子高管出现首张中国面孔
>
> 西门子中国没有职位上的‘天花板’,从CEO,到业务总裁,越来越多的中国面孔跻身西门子高管团队,我的责任就是让有能力有经验的本土化员工迅速成长起来,担纲西门子中国以至全球的重任。

BTW: I can't find your sentence exactly on Baidu, but I found this, which used the word `本土` for `localization`.

> 西门子这样一个跨国公司，已经开始选择完全的本土脸孔来拉近和中国的距离。

[西门子高管出现首张中国面孔](http://www.cdwb.com.cn/html/2010-12/24/content_1146806.htm?lwjcldxufrsrpcvx)
[程美玮:西门子中国没有天花板](http://news.163.com/10/0812/08/6DSEL9PJ00014AED.html?f=jsearch)
[西门子本土化"模板" 用本土人管理上海业务](http://www.wenzhouglasses.com/html/news/401979.html)

Comment: Good, no nasty surprises there then! The text has the title '西门子的本土化‘ 谢谢您！

Answer (score 1):

I am from China, and I was surprised to find Chinese Language forum at stackexchange.

面孔 is not equal to English word “Face".

已经开始选择完全的中国面孔来拉近和中国的距离 means (Siemens) employ Chinese citizens in  the top of company, let local people to manage local business.

However, you may not notice that before 中国面孔 there is a adjective 完全的 which means total/complete. So, you can describe a Asian people as 中国面孔,like 那个人是中国面孔（That man has a Chinese face)中国面孔, but in fact , He may be a Japanese.

That's all right, because 中国面孔 means someone looks like a Chinese people.